# Validation Summary MessageBox not displaying

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to display my Validation Summary in a MessageBox and it simply inst working. Here's what I have.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="100%"ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False"></asp:ValidationSummary>

<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="label" Width="138px">* Serial Number</asp:Label>
 </td>
 <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSerial" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valSerial" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="txtSerial" ErrorMessage="Serial number is required" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </td>
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Height="20px"></asp:Button>
```

I have followed every guide I can find on the internet but i can't get it to work.
What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: It's working here.(after I put a space between `Width` and `ShowMessageBox`, but that should give a parser error anyway). I suggest you check your browser console for javascript/jQuery errors.

Comment: ShowSummary="False", shouldn't it be True?

Comment: @AmanB no it does not have to be.

Comment: My console isn't displaying any errors for the page. This is very odd. Could it have anything to do with running the page through IIS Express? Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it. I had `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` in my web config. This prevented the MessageBox from displaying.